# Function to remove rows from table not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a question about my function remove(btn). I can't quite figure it out why its not working. This function have a button when i click it it is supposed to add it to the remove table and increase the counter, meanwhile decrease the counter from the main table and remove the row from there.
Here is my code:

```js
var title = document.getElementById("title");
var author = document.getElementById("author");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

function addToTable() {
  var radio = document.getElementsByName("content");
  var radio_selected;
  for (var a = 0; a < radio.length; a++) {
    if (radio[a].checked) {
      radio_selected = radio[a].value;
    }
  }
  output.innerHTML += "<tr>" + "<td>" + title.value + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + author.value + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + radio_selected + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + "<input type='button' onclick='post(this);' value ='Post'>" +
    "<input type='button' onclick='remove(this);' value ='Remove'>" + "</td>" + "</tr>"
}

function counter() {
  var brojac = document.getElementById("counterForElements");
  brojac.innerHTML = parseInt(brojac.innerHTML) + 1;
}

function remove(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  var removed = document.getElementById("removed");
  removed.append(row);
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
  var brojac = document.getElementById("counterForElements"); //counter
  brojac.innerHTML = parseInt(brojac.innerHTML) - 1; //counter
}

function post(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "Green";
  btn.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  btn.parentNode.lastElementChild.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
}
```

```css
label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

table,
th,
td,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <label for="Title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="Author">Author</label>
    <input type="text" id="author">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="content" id="contentlabel">Content type</label>
    <input type="radio" name="content" value="Free" class="content">Free
    <input type="radio" name="content" value="Paid" class="content">Paid
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addToTable(); counter();">
</div>
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th style="width:40%;">Title</th>
      <th style="width:40%;">Author</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">Type</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">Button</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="output">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Number of elements: <span id="counterForElements">0</span></h1>
  <h1>Removed elements</h1>
  <table id="removed">

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What are the steps we need to take to see this not work? What is expected result?

Comment: @mplungjan add title,author and then add it to the main table by clicking the add button then when its added it should pop up 2 buttons on right post and remove click on remove button and its supposed to remove the row

Comment: I see there's already an answer. I'll just explain what the issue was. When you append a node to a new parent, that node is moved, not copied. Therefore, removing the node after moving it, will remove it from the new table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your append is moving the row which means this will DELETE the row regardless of which table it is in: `row.parentNode.removeChild(row);`

I strongly recommend counting the actual rows

Also delegating (eventListener on the tbody) makes the code simpler and allows us to remove the inline event handlers.

Lastly an array to keep the data in and a map to render it

```js
const titleField = document.getElementById("title");
const authorField = document.getElementById("author");
const output = document.getElementById("output");
const add = document.getElementById("add");
const brojac = document.getElementById("counterForElements");
const removed = document.getElementById("removed");
const arr = [];
const counter = () => brojac.textContent = output.querySelectorAll("tr").length;
const render = () => output.innerHTML = arr
  .map(({ title, author, paymentType },i) => `<tr data-idx="${i}">
     <td>${title}</td>   
     <td>${author}</td>
     <td>${paymentType}</td>
     <td><input type="button" class="post" value="Post" />
     <input type="button" class="remove" value="Remove"></td>
   </tr>`).join("");


const addToTable = () => {
  const paymentType = document.querySelector("[name=content]:checked")?.value ?? "";
  const author = authorField.value
  const title = titleField.value
  arr.push({ author, title, paymentType })
  render()
  counter();
};

output.addEventListener("click", e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.matches(".remove")) {
    const row = tgt.closest("tr");
    arr.splice(+row.dataset.idx,1); // removing the element from the array at index    
    removed.append(row);
    counter(); // count what's left
  } else if (tgt.matches(".post")) {
    var row = tgt.closest("tr");
    row.style.backgroundColor = "Green";
    tgt.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
    tgt.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  }
})

add.addEventListener("click", addToTable)
```

```css
label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

table,
th,
td,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <label for="Title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="Author">Author</label>
    <input type="text" id="author">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="content" id="contentlabel">Content type</label>
    <input type="radio" name="content" value="Free" class="content">Free
    <input type="radio" name="content" value="Paid" class="content">Paid
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Add" id="add" />
</div>
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th style="width:40%;">Title</th>
      <th style="width:40%;">Author</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">Type</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">Button</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="output">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Number of elements: <span id="counterForElements">0</span></h1>
  <h1>Removed elements</h1>
  <table id="removed">

  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the mistake, just replace your code by:

```
function remove(btn) {
    var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
    var removed = document.getElementById("removed");
    removed.append(row);
    var brojac = document.getElementById("counterForElements");//counter
    brojac.innerHTML = parseInt(brojac.innerHTML) - 1;//counter
}
```

I removed this statement: `row.parentNode.removeChild(row);`.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have counters for added items & removed items, here is something that you can try - adding an additional span for the removed items so you can see the number

HTML

```
            <h1>Number of elements: <span id="counterForElements">0</span></h1>
            <h1>Removed elements: <span id="counterForElements1">0</span></h1>
```

and then

JS

```
        function remove(btn){
            var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
            var removed = document.getElementById("removed");
            removed.append(row); 
            row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
            var brojac = document.getElementById("counterForElements");
            var brojac1 = document.getElementById("counterForElements1");//counter
            brojac1.innerHTML = parseInt(brojac1.innerHTML) - 1;//counter
            brojac.innerHTML = parseInt(brojac.innerHTML) - 1;
        }
```

I think that those were all the changes that I made, you can see what your code looks like with those changes here -

[codepen](https://codepen.io/esteecodes/pen/xxYBrgL)

This is just an example id name, you can use whatever you like 
and - it all depends on what your final goal is.

Comment: If you click the `[<>]` snippet editor button, you can post the code here instead of codepen